# inline CSS style is not getting rendered [Previously: Component is not rendering its elements - react]

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, reactjs

I am learning React. I am trying to render the following component, (contents of index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class d3Dash extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
<div style={{width:200,height:100,border:1,color:"black"}}>Hellow!!</div>
);
}
}

//==============================================================================
```

`ReactDOM.render(
   <d3Dash/>, document.getElementById('d3Root')
   );`

My index.html file is as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script async src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="d3Root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure out why, but div doesn't render itself as a rectangular box in the page. Whereas, when I insert the same code inside the body of the html page it does render itself as a black rectangular box. Could someone shed some light on how to debug this? Or is it an issue with JSX syntax?

As an addition, my package.json is,

```
{
"name": "reactdash",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "D3js - react interactive visualization dashboard",
"main": "index.js",
"proxy": "http://'127.0.0.1':3002",
"keywords": [
"d3",
"react"
],
"author": "Russell Bertrand",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.35.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
"htmltojsx": "^0.2.6",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-scripts": "^1.0.10",
"webpack": "^3.2.0"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit out the original code after having received answers. It's crucial for answers to make sense.

Comment: Looks like, JSX is not being transpiled. Any idea how to debug and fix this?

Comment: I figured that out as only the inline CSS is not being rendered. I have surfed the net but none seem to help much. Any help as to how to debug would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You nailed it. It's an issue with JSX.

In React, any component you define must begin with a capital letter, otherwise it's assumed that they are plain old html dom nodes.

Redefine your component as `D3Dash` instead.

**Edit:** Also, be sure you're exporting your component properly. The class definition should read:

`export class D3Dash extends React.Component`

or

`export default class D3Dash extends React.Component`

depending on how you are importing this component. If you've declared this component in the same file that you mount it via `ReactDOM.render`, then disregard.

**Edit:** Also, the inline styles on that div seem inconsistent with your description. For instance, `color` is the css property for text color, and `border` requires more than just a number.

Is it possible that you intended to do this instead:

```
<div style={{
  background: 'black',
  color: 'white',
  width: '200px',
  height: '100px',
  border: '1px solid black' }}>Hellow!!</div>
```

**Edit:** Your `index.html` is missing the script tag that brings in your webpack bundle.

Comment: Hi Danny, Thanks. However, renaming doesn't help. Still the code inside the <div> </div> is not getting rendered. :(

Comment: Are you exporting your D3Dash component properly? See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks danny. That doesn't help either. I have added my package.json. Is there anything that I should have it for the JSX to be rendered properly? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Also, double check that you're bringing in your webpack bundle in your `index.html` page.

Comment: Thank you Danny. I tried your inline styles, but in vain. I am not getting what you mean by bringing webpack bundle in index.html. Thank you Once again

Comment: Where in your `index.html` file are you bringing in your `index.js` file after it's been bundled by webpack? There should be a script tag for that.

Comment: I have managed to get the 'bundle.js' work. However, inline style CSS descriptions are not being rendered. Any help?